# Pymunk and Pygame circle randomly flys to a diffrent direction when placed inside of a poly

Tags: python, pygame, physics, pymunk

I have a ball/circle inside of a poly,but It just goes to a random direction. I think it is because of Pymunk to Pygame position. Are you supposed to make the lists an int to make it work with pygame?(thats what I did) or do you convert the points another way? I also noticed if I print the Container's postion it comes out as (0,0)

```
import pygame, sys, pymunk
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/yN0u9Ia" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/yN0u9Ia"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = (0, 500)


#Varibales
CircleRadius = 10
OctogonPoints = [(400, 200), (800, 200), (1082.505, 483.18), (1082.505, 883.18), (800, 1166.36), (400, 1166), (117.495, 883), (117.495, 483.18)]
OctogonScaleingFactor = 0.6
ScaledOctogonPoints = []
PygameOctogonPonits = []
for x, y in OctogonPoints:
    changedX = x * OctogonScaleingFactor
    changedY = y * OctogonScaleingFactor

    changedX += 140
    changedY += 0
    ScaledOctogonPoints.append((changedX, changedY))
for x,y in ScaledOctogonPoints:
    PygameChangedX = int(x)
    PygameChangedY = int(y)
    PygameOctogonPonits.append((PygameChangedX, PygameChangedY))
# create ball
BallBody = pymunk.Body(1, 100, body_type=pymunk.Body.DYNAMIC)
BallBody.position = 500, 400
BallBody.velocity = (0, 0)
BallShape = pymunk.Circle(BallBody, CircleRadius)
BallShape.elasticity = 0.9
BallShape.collision_type = 1
space.add(BallBody, BallShape)

# Create Container
ContainerBody = pymunk.Body(1000,1000,pymunk.Body.STATIC)


ContainerShape = pymunk.Poly(ContainerBody, ScaledOctogonPoints, radius=1)
ContainerShape.collision_type = 2
ContainerShape.elasticity= 1
space.add(ContainerBody, ContainerShape)

#handle collisions
def Collision(arbiter, space, data):
        print("Collision")
        global CircleRadius, BallShape
        CircleRadius += 2
        space.remove(BallShape)
        BallShape = pymunk.Circle(BallBody, CircleRadius)
        BallShape.elasticity = 0.9
        BallShape.collision_type = 1
        space.add(BallShape)



#handler = space.add_collision_handler(1, 2)
#handler.separate = Collision

#main game loop
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    #draw bodys in pygame
    Bx, By = BallBody.position
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), (int(Bx), int(By)), CircleRadius)
    Octogon = pygame.draw.lines(screen, (255, 255, 255), True, PygameOctogonPonits, 1)

    space.step(1 / 50)



    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Video
https://imgur.com/a/yN0u9Ia

I tried ChatGPT but I had no hope, same with things online

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem - it turns out that polys are filled and are not hollow.